# join two lists by interleaving

Tags: python

I have a list that I create by parsing some text.
Let's say the list looks like

```
charlist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

I would like to take the following list

```
numlist = [3, 2, 1]
```

and join it together so that my combined list looks like

```
[['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['c', 1]]
```

is there a simple method for this?

Comment: Have you read about `zip()` yet?  A search of SO would reveal that.

Comment: no; i hadn't.  thanks for letting me know about it.  i tried searching SO quite a bit for this problem and didn't know how to phrase it to yield the best results.  thank you.

Comment: wish you had answered the q- i would mark it correct!  :)

Comment: @jml: I'm a little surprised that searching SO quite a bit for this didn't find the answer.  I'm also a little surprised that you haven't looked at the Python built-in functions, either.  The list of functions is short, and very helpful.  http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html.  More helpful than asking questions here.

Comment: @S.Lott, unless you've had a functional programming course, one might not even expect something like this to be in a standard API. :)

Comment: @sarnold: While true, I would think that the list of built-in functions was required reading before asking duplicate questions.

Comment: @S.Lott, it doesn't seem to me the OP would necessary have been able to discover the alleged dup based on the vocabulary at his diposal. (and in fact, why not mark it is a dup if it is one?)  While `zip` is a fine name for the function, it's not *necessarily* intuitive -- hence the OP's choice of words.  And IMO, SO is indeed a forum for those who have not in fact read the docs for a given language's API from cover to cover.

Comment: @Kirk I agree that zip is an unintuitive function name, when I first encountered it I assumed it was a compression method. Interleaving is a perfectly reasonable term to search for.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: "why not mark it is a dup if it is one?"  Because I agree with you that it's not an obvious, trivial duplicate.  My point is not that it is a duplicate.  My point is that a search would probably have revealed enough related questions to point to an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) builtin function should do the trick.

Example from the docs:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zipped = zip(x, y)
>>> zipped
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want a list of lists rather than a list of tuples you could use:

```
map(list,zip(charlist,numlist))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another easy way to do it.

```
charlist = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numlist = [3, 2, 1]
newlist = []

for key, a in enumerate(charlist):
    newlist.append([a,numlist[key]])
```

Content of newlist: `[['a', 3], ['b', 2], ['c', 1]]`

Answer (score 1):

```
p=[] 
for i in range(len(charlist)): 
    p.append([charlist[i],numlist[i]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following, though I am sure there are going to be better approaches:

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = [1, 2, 3]    
l = []
for i in 1:length(l1):
    l.append([l1[i], l2[i]])
```

All the best.